# can we create same store view for multiple websites in magento

Tags: magento, multistore

I have multiple store website in which I want to add feature of language in url. I have created store view name with code 'en' for first site (for ex. www.site-one.com) so that user can open www.site-one.com/en.

Now I want to create the same for second site but using the same code for second site (for ex. www.site-two.com) is giving error "Store with the same code already exists.".

Is this possible to create same store code for more than one site so that user can also open www.site-two.com/en

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: yes if can be solved through programming but I think it is just htaccess and rewrite rules of magento. And can be done programmatically if we edit the core code of magento so that a store view can be created with multiple websites.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunateley not. The store code in the `core_store` database table has a unique key and changing this will break lots of things in Magento.

A possible workaround is not to use the "prepend store code" configuration and instead configure the base urls for the stores like `http://www.site-one.com/en/`. Then create a rewrite rule (for example using `.htaccess`) to direct all requests from `/en/*` to `/*` and so on.

#### Example configuration

<del>For the store codes *en*, *fr* and *de*:</del>

<del>RewriteRule ^(?:en|fr|de)/(.*)$ $1 [QSA]</del>

<del>This should be placed before all other rewrite rules.</del>

OK I tested it and indeed got a 404 error from Magento, probably because it tries to evaluate the request URI relative to `index.php`.

The usual approach seems to be to actually create the subdirectories, copy `index.php` and `.htaccess`, and either

1. symlink all other directories (`en/app -> app` etc.) **or**
2. adjust index.php to point to the correct `Mage.php` and configure only the **web** base url with subdirectory, so that js, media and skin files still are loaded from their original path.

(1) definitely works, I have done it in the past. (2) should work but there might be some more things to consider

Comment: I am not good with htaccess. can you please elaborate. it'll be very helpful.

Comment: My bad. Remove `L` from the flags, that prevented further processing of the original rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89897/discussion-between-user0509-and-fschmengler).

Comment: symlinks worked but it is not working for magento pages like /customer/account/create.